# Prevent lazy loading in nHibernate

Tags: silverlight, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, lazy-loading

I'm storing some blobs in my database, so I have a Document table and a DocumentContent table.  Document contains a filename, description etc and has a DocumentContent property.

I have a Silverlight client, so I don't want to load up and send the DocumentContent to the client unless I explicity ask for it, but I'm having trouble doing this.

I've read the blog post by [Davy Brion](http://davybrion.com/blog/2009/03/must-everything-be-virtual-with-nhibernate/).  I have tried placing lazy=false in my config and removing the virtual access modifier but have had no luck with it as yet.

Every time I do a Session.Get(id), the DocumentContent is retrieved via an outer join.  I only want this property to be populated when I explicity join onto this table and ask for it.

Any help is appreciated.

My NHibernate mapping is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="Jrm.Model"
                   namespace="Jrm.Model">
  <class name="JrmDocument" lazy="false">
    <id name="JrmDocumentID">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>

    <property name="FileName"/>
    <property name="Description"/>
    <many-to-one name="DocumentContent" class="JrmDocumentContent" unique="true" column="JrmDocumentContentID" lazy="false"/>
  </class>


  <class name="JrmDocumentContent" lazy="false">
    <id name="JrmDocumentContentID">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>

    <property name="Content" type="BinaryBlob" lazy="false">
      <column name="FileBytes" sql-type="varbinary(max)"/>
    </property>

  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and my classes are:

```
[DataContract]   
    public class JrmDocument : ModelBase
    {
        private int jrmDocumentID;
        private JrmDocumentContent documentContent;
        private long maxFileSize;
        private string fileName;
        private string description;

        public JrmDocument()
        {
        }

        public JrmDocument(string fileName, long maxFileSize)
        {
            DocumentContent = new JrmDocumentContent(File.ReadAllBytes(fileName));
            FileName = new FileInfo(fileName).Name;
        }

        [DataMember]
        public virtual int JrmDocumentID
        {
            get { return jrmDocumentID; }
            set
            {
                jrmDocumentID = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("JrmDocumentID");
            }
        }               

        [DataMember]
        public JrmDocumentContent DocumentContent
        {
            get { return documentContent; }
            set
            {
                documentContent = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("DocumentContent");
            }
        }        

        [DataMember]
        public virtual long MaxFileSize
        {
            get { return maxFileSize; }
            set
            {
                maxFileSize = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("MaxFileSize");
            }
        }


        [DataMember]
        public virtual string FileName
        {
            get { return fileName; }
            set
            {
                fileName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FileName");
            }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public virtual string Description
        {
            get { return description; }
            set
            {
                description = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Description");
            }
        }
    }



    [DataContract]
    public class JrmDocumentContent : ModelBase
    {
        private int jrmDocumentContentID;
        private byte[] content;

        public JrmDocumentContent()
        {
        }
        public JrmDocumentContent(byte[] bytes)
        {
            Content = bytes;
        }

        [DataMember]
        public int JrmDocumentContentID
        {
            get { return jrmDocumentContentID; }
            set
            {
                jrmDocumentContentID = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("JrmDocumentContentID");
            }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public byte[] Content
        {
            get { return content; }
            set
            {
                content = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Content");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like lazy loading is just what you want

Comment: It's not what I want at all.  Consider the UI experience.  I will have a list of Documents that the user may be selecting 0+ of.  I don't want the DocumentContent to be retrieved until I explicitly ask for it - this would be a huge performance drag to load up all the DocumentContents if the user isn't even going to use them.  So when a user clicks on a document, I will have a 2nd service call to actually retrieve the Document including the DocumentContent

Comment: The reason I don't want lazy loading is that, I first want to send a list of Documents to the client, the user will then select one of these Documents and I will then retrieve the Document including the DocumentContent for them to save.
Because I am using Silverlight, when the Document is serialized, the DocumentContent is getting touched and then lazily loaded.  If I turn lazy loading off, then it is fetched eagerly.  I just don't want it retrieved at all

Comment: If it feels like an uphill battle to get what you're doing working, you're probably doing it wrong. Many people smarter than myself have been down this road many times before, and the conclusion is nearly always the same: use DTOs. They exist for the exact reason you're describing, to transfer the data that is required by the consumer, no more, no less. The maintenance issue of DTOs is a misnomer with the advent of projects like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a problem with where my relationship was being managed (inverse=true) and also with my session instantiation as it was being injected in.  Using that in conjunction with a custom DataContractSurrogate that prevented some of the lazy loading issues now works.

Thanks

```
var proxy = obj as INHibernateProxy; 
if (proxy != null) 
{ 
    var initializer = proxy.HibernateLazyInitializer; 
    if (initializer.IsUninitialized) 
    { 
        return Activator.CreateInstance(obj.GetType().BaseType); } 
    else 
    { 
        return initializer.GetImplementation(); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to defer loading, then set lazy="true" in your map.

Comment: I've tried lazy="true" and lazy="false".  Neither give the desired effect.  I don't want the DocumentContent to be loaded - lazily or otherwise unless I explicitly do it via a select criteria.
I've used LLBL Gen previously and in the adapter model the relationships are not loaded unless explicitly requested via a Prefetch.  I want to do something similar in nHibernate

Answer (score 2):

You should use DTOs for your service and leave all with lazy = true instead of serializing you domain model. It's a big performance gain.

Comment: I don't want to change my app over to DTO's now.  A lot of my classes are quite lightweight and in most cases are working perfectly

Answer (score 1):

First rule of thumb:

- do not distribute your domain objects

http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FirstLaw.html

Comment: Following every law blindly isn't always possible.

Answer (score 0):

The scenario you have described is exactly what lazy loading is designed for.

You want to display a list containing summary information and when required load the heavier stuff. This is lazy loading. It is "lazy" because it avoids doing extra work until it absolutely needs to.

What you want is for the JrmDocumentContent to be loaded lazily and you're well on th way to that. To get this you have to remove the lazy=false. lazy=true is the default in nhibernate but you may put lazy=true to be sure. You'll have to restore the virtuals though.

Loading blobs lazily like this or any property for that matter, I think is supported in nhibernate's latest release now by setting lazy=true on the property definition.

The method you have used by separating the heavy content into a separate class/table was the only way to lazily load a blob before. I don't know what version of nhibernate you're using but the strategy you have adopted is correct. You should embrace lazy loading. You also need to remove lazy=false on the Content property of the JrmDocumentContent class. Apart from that, I see no other reason why it shouln't work.

Answer (score 0):

I've had exactly this problem.

Here's what I've done:

1. Create my own custom proxy (using Castle DynamicProxy, but you can try others) that returns `null` on all un-initialized properties and collections, and returns a copy of each initialized collection. I wrap each root object result in my service with such a proxy. Pass this proxy as the return value of my service - almost works, except that I couldn't get my proxies themselves to be serialized correctly. That's why I tried method 2:
2. (Horrible) Deeply clone all my entities into new objects, skipping uninitialized properties and collections. This works, but sucks.
3. Currently I'm trying to use DataContractSurrogate to solve the problem in 1. or to replace the use of proxies altogether. The problem I'm  currently trying to solve is that you can't "filter" object properties - you can't return `null` from [GetObjectToSerialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.idatacontractsurrogate.getobjecttoserialize%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) - which is exactly what I want to return if the object being serialized is an uninitialized NHibernate proxy or collection.

I'll update this answer when I progress. Currently I'm using solution 2 as a temporary workaround. I'd share the code but it's a mess currently (since I wasn't intending deep-cloning to be the solution).

Comment: This was solved usint the DataContractSurrogate. I can check if something is a proxy and overwrite the property and set it to a new default instance. i.e. var proxy = obj as INHibernateProxy; if (proxy != null) { var initializer = proxy.HibernateLazyInitializer; if (initializer.IsUninitialized) { return Activator.CreateInstance(obj.GetType().BaseType); } else { return initializer.GetImplementation(); } }

Comment: I've considered this solution, but then we serialize empty instances instead of nulls. Not only is this a waste in communications, it also means the client can't tell whether the object it received was really not fetched from the DB, or simply has all its fields set to default values (empty instance) in the database.

Comment: BTW, instead of running a deep clone I now pass my custom proxies directly to the serializer in combination with a DataContractSurrogate that just replaces the contract type of the custom proxy to the base class (proxied class) type. The NHibernate proxies contained within are automatically masked out by my custom proxy. Still not a perfect solution, but at least the resulting communication is what I want it to be, and no deep clone is necessary.